# boost_logging fails to compile, because of 'CRITICAL_SECTION' : ambiguous symbol

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, boost-logging

I am using [boost_logging](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/index.html) for my project.

In one of my file I just use my logging facility:
 `LDBG_ << "something"`
but it does not seam to compile, I have the following error:

```
1>c:\boost\boost_logging\boost\logging\detail\ts\ts_win32.hpp(57) : error C2872: 'CRITICAL_SECTION' : ambiguous symbol    
1>        could be 'c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\winbase.h(314) : RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION CRITICAL_SECTION'   
1>        or 'c:\boost\boost135\boost\detail\lwm_win32_cs.hpp(33) : boost::detail::CRITICAL_SECTION'
```

The weird part is that this is working fine on one of my PC, but not on the other, so it might be the winbase.h include that is different.

**EDIT:**

Here is how the LDBG_ log is defined:

```
#include <boost/logging/format_fwd.hpp>
#include <boost/logging/format_ts.hpp>

typedef boost::logging::scenario::usage::use<
        //  the filter is always accurate (but slow)
        //boost::logging::scenario::usage::filter_::change::always_accurate, 
        boost::logging::scenario::usage::filter_::change::often< 10 >,
        //  filter does not use levels
        boost::logging::scenario::usage::filter_::level::no_levels, 
        // the logger is initialized once, when only one thread is running
        boost::logging::scenario::usage::logger_::change::set_once_when_one_thread, 
        // the logger favors speed (on a dedicated thread)
        boost::logging::scenario::usage::logger_::favor::speed> finder;

BOOST_DECLARE_LOG_FILTER(g_log_filter, finder::filter ) 
BOOST_DECLARE_LOG(g_log_dbg, finder::logger)

#define LDBG_ BOOST_LOG_USE_LOG_IF_FILTER(g_log_dbg(), g_log_filter()->is_enabled() )
```

Comment: We need to see more of the code including the declaration of LDGG_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try including boost logging headers *before* windows headers.

Comment: I have moved my log header #include (the one that defines LDBG_) to the top of my includes, and it works well. Thanks a lot.